# Windows 7: Shortcut Key remains after shortcut deleted

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, keyboard-shortcuts

A few days ago I was playing around with using shortcut keys. You know, these:
[image]

Accidently I set the shortcut to AltGr+ç which prints '{'. Now as a developer, you can imagine I need this key-combination quite a lot.

The problem is, that after changing the shortkey, deleting the shortcut, ... the key combination is still active. And everytime I press this combination in my Visual Studio, it just removes focus from the main window.

Is there a way to get a list of active shortcut keys and edit them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somehow managed to get my Windows 7 in the same state when testing this. I had a shortcut with a None shortcut key and my previously assigned hotkey `Ctrl+Alt+6` still opened the shortcut.

With [NirSoft RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) I determined that keys at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist\{CEBFF5CD-ACE2-4F4F-9178-9926F41749EA}\Count` get modified when a new shortcut key is assigned.

I poked around the keys and I remember deleting `HRZR_PGYFRFFVBA` because it contained the path to my shortcut.

Finally I logged off and logged in again, and my shortcut keys were back to normal. I'm not sure but I assume that simply restarting/relogging should fix this, without needing to delete any registry keys.

Comment: I'll try this. I usually hibernate my laptop as it takes way too long for it to completely boot everytime.